# Login to website using jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I tried to look everywhere to find a solution for my problem without any success. I'm trying to login to http://www.dailystrength.org/ website, however, my code doesn't work properly since I'm seeing that my crawler can't access some users' profiles that are private for non-registered members.

Here is my code:

```
String loginUrl = source + "/index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=login";
Document login = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl).timeout(20000).get();
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
Elements inputs = login.select("input");

for(Element input : inputs)
{
    parameters.put(input.attr("name"), input.attr("value"));
}

parameters.put("username", "user");
parameters.put("passwd", "pass");
parameters.put("remember", "yes");

cookies = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl).data(parameters).method(org.jsoup
          .Connection.Method.POST).timeout(20000).execute().cookies();
```

I tried also to include hidden input values, but it didn't work too. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: can you elaborate on " I'm seeing that my crawler can't access some users' profiles that are private for non-registered members."?

Comment: Also what is the error you are getting?

Comment: So in the website, there are two types of profiles, first type you can see their information if you are not logged in, and the other type of profiles you need to log in in order to see their information. Here, I'm creating a crawler to store the website information including users' profiles. When I check it, it can't access the private users' profiles since it's not logged in, even that I'm not seeing any error when I run it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use Htmlunit and jsoup. For login use Htmlunit, its easy, you just need to submit form with username and password, after login, new page will come and you can deal with jsoup with that new page.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what u were trying to do

```
String loginUrl = "http://www.dailystrength.org/" + "/index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=login";
    Document login = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl).timeout(20000).header("username", "user").header("passwd", "pass").header("remember", "yes").post();
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Elements inputs = login.select("input");
for(Element input : inputs)
{
    String thi= input.attr("name");
    String  thi2=input.attr("value");
    System.out.println("THIS" + thi);
    System.out.println("THIS2" + thi2);
parameters.put(input.attr("name"), input.attr("value"));
}
```

Hope this works for u